# php email cut off only for some recipients

Tags: php, email

I have a really simple email script that I'm using in conjunction with a form.

```
<?php 
$fName = $_POST;
$access = array_values($fName);
$emailString ="         Name: ".$access[0]." ".$access[1]."\n
                Organization: ".$access[2]."\n
                Email: ".$access[3]."\n
                Number: ".$access[4]."\n
                What They Wrote: ".$access[5]."\n";

$to = "clients@email.com, my@email.com";
$messageSubject = "Somebody has contacted you from ClientsWebSite";
$messageBody = wordwrap($emailString, 55, "\n");
$headers = "From: noreply@clientswebsite.com\r\n" ."X-Mailer: php";

if(mail($to, $messageSubject, $messageBody, $headers)){
    echo("<script> var mailSent = true </script>");
}else{
    echo("<script> var mailSent = false </script>");
}

    ?>
```

The code above is for a really quick and dirty "Send a Comment" type of form. The problem is, as you can see I have the email sending to mine and the clients email address. I have gmail, and I recieve the letter in full, like so:

> noreply@clientswebsite.com 11:23 AM (5 minutes ago)
>
> to client, me
>
> ```
>                                    Name: One MoreTime
>
>                                    Organization: WeGottaDancin
>
>                                    Email: OoohYeah@wegottheDancin.com
>
>                                    Number: 0123456789
>
>                                    What They Wrote:  ONE MORE TIME
> ```

But when he gets the email, the "what they wrote" section of the email is not there. I've done some searching around and haven't been able to come up with a working solution.

Anybody have an idea?

Comment: If the same email is going to two addresses, and is showing up differently, I'd say the problem is with their email client, or possibly their server. Can you get the client to look at the full source of the email, and see if the text is included there? It might not be showing up for some reason....

Comment: you may have to post your full code, form etc.

Comment: @andrewsi - I guess it is a problem with their server, the full text isn't anywhere in the email. I just don't understand why the last line is getting cut off.

Comment: You could try adding a hard-wired couple of lines at the end of the email you send, so if it is cutting stuff off, it'll lose those instead of the important stuff?

Comment: @Fred - There's really not much to see. It works fine, I've tested what my server outputting. Before the email gets sent, the value of $messageBody exactly what should be sent

Comment: @andrewsi Thanks this worked perfectly. I would still like to know what's going on here, hopefully an answer will come through. It's one of those things that's so simple I can't believe it worked.

Comment: Just curious, but did your extra text get truncated, too?

Comment: yup. A bit strange no? gmail and godaddy email worked fine. clients email, for whatever reason, is cutting off the last line.